# Using StringBuild to change string to lowercase only for uneven positioned letters

Tags: c#, stringbuilder, uppercase, lowercase, letter

I am currently learning c# with an online tutorial. So far I have been able to solve every exercise but this one I cannot figure it out:

***Write a program asking the user a string. Then it will modify the string by changing uneven letters (first, third...) into lowercase and even letters (second, fourth...) into uppercase letters. For instance: "Hello" should look like this --> hElLo.***

I am converting the string to uppercase first so I only have to do the lowercase part. In this exercise I am supposed to use StringBuilder but I cannot figure it out. I thought maybe with a `for` *loop* I could go through every letter and change those that `i%2 != 0` but `StringBuilder` *cannot* use `ToLower()`. I cannot think of a way to change it `ToString()`, `ToLower()`and then add it at the end of the string.

Any help will be welcome.

Mario.

Comment: You call `ToLower()` on each string before you add it to the `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Where are you getting the requirement for `StringBuilder`?

Comment: The exercise is in the StringBuilder lesson of the course.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `StringBuilder` doesn't have `ToLower()`, but you can use `char.ToLower` for *each character*:

```
 string source = "Abracadba";

 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(source.Length);

 for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; ++i) {
   sb.Append(i % 2 != 0
     ? char.ToUpper(source[i]) 
     : char.ToLower(source[i]));
 }

 string result = sb.ToString();
```

Same idea, *Linq* implementation:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string result = string.Concat(source
   .Select((c, i) => i % 2 != 0 ? char.ToUpper(c) : char.ToLower(c)));
```

Comment: Great!! Works perfect! Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: @MarioDuran mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score -1):

*Tho this is not an ideal question to answer, but just wanted to share a little knowledge*

It's quite easy. Loop through the `char`s of the string, detect if the `char`'s index is odd or even and do your work there :

```
// A simple function to check if a number is odd

public static bool IsOdd(int value)
{
    return value % 2 != 0;
}

// Now looping through the characters

public string ManipulatedString(string str)
{
 string manipulated = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
 {
    if(IsOdd(i))
       manipulated += Char.ToUpper(str[i]);
    else
       manipulated += Char.ToLower(str[i]);
 }
 return manipulated;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: `str[i]` is `char`, and in case of `char` the syntax is `char.ToUpper(str[i])` (`char.ToLower(str[i])`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks mate! Missed it.